# Hide table header if no results after filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a `table` containing some data. And i have to filters on this data.

When, after filtering data, there is no results, i want to show a "no results" message, and it works.

But i also want to hide the table completely when there are no results.

Here is a demo :

http://plnkr.co/edit/iSbr9Ij4wsX947JqAsEB?p=preview

I tried :

```
<table  ng-if="results.length > 0">
```

But that gave me a js error

Is there a way to hide the table if there are no results to show ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this does not feel right, but it works :)

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:{annee:annee.id}  | filter:myFilter as results" ng-if="$first"> 
    <th>column1</th>
    <th>column2</th>
  </tr>
```

*EDIT* This feels nicer .

```
<header ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  Header {{ item }}
</header>
<div class="body">
  Body {{ item }}
</div>
<footer ng-repeat-end>
  Footer {{ item }}
</footer>
```

Comment: I still see the table if no results :/

Comment: Ok i mis read. It works but, i still obtain an empty table, there's no way to make the table disappear if no results ?

Comment: still don't like it

<table ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:{annee:annee.id}  | filter:myFilter as results" ng-if="$first">

Comment: if you have a google for AngularJS table there are some neat ones and I presume they do this

Comment: When I say do this I mean do what you need but without the ng-if which tbh is probably fine just does not feel pure 